# Stuck on the phone

Tags: work-environment, hiring-process, work-experience, promotion, unprofessional-behavior

I work in a call center for almost 2 years now. In the 2 years I've seen a number of people who started after me promoted to positions over me. I too applied to any open position available. I've heard rumors here and there stating that my superiors don't want me off the phones because I'm so polite.

I'm confused and lost as to what I should do. If this is true, am I being type casted to the phones while people who are probably just ok and only a fraction of my Etiquette and experience being here are promoted to other positions. Is it my own fault for being good at what they want me to do? Is it wrong or illegal keeping me in one position while promoting newbies over me? When I started they said there would be career growth but I don't think it’s contractual. I never got it in writing that they promise me specifically any promotion. Should I leave this job? Should I stay and just ignore this company using me and giving the rewards of my work to other people. I want to quit thinking this could happen here what’s to stop it from happening again. Or if I leave what can I do to prevent this from happening at another job.

Comment: Why don't you suggest a career path for people they want to keep on the phones? Are you looking for status, money or do you no longer want to talk on the phone?

Comment: VTC as advice. We can't tell you what to do. That said, why are you looking for a career in a *call center*? And if you think promoting other people could be illegal you're in for a rude awakening.

Comment: Considering your Job as being in a call center I think changing your company will be helpful you can apply  for an upper position and change if you get selected for some better position.

Comment: Are there positions that you can apply for where you can train the new staff on phone etiquette? If you train new people who are as effective on the phones as you are, your manager might be less tempted to hold you hostage.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it wrong or illegal keeping me in one position while promoting
>   newbies over me?

Unless your contract states otherwise (very, very unlikely), then it isn't illegal to be passed over for a promotion.

> Should I leave this job?

That's up to you to decide. But it would be rather foolish to leave based on a rumor.

It's exceedingly unlikely that the reason you aren't getting promoted is because you are "so polite". I know that some workers feel that they aren't being promoted because they are so good at their job. But in my more than 45 years of work experience, that's simply a myth. You can't really think that nobody that gets promoted is polite. If that were truly the case, then the easiest way to be promoted would be to simply stop being polite. That's clearly not going to work.

Do you ever talk with your boss? Do you have regular one-on-one meetings? Have you ever asked about this?

If it were me, I'd talk with my boss privately. I'd say something like "I've been working really hard for the past 2 years, boss. What can I do to get myself in position to be promoted?"

I suspect that you'd find something (more training, more productivity, different work habits, changed hours, fewer errors, or some other improvement) that could help you further your career path. I can't believe your boss would say "stop being so polite".

Answer (score -1):

I know not desirable but put in for a lateral change.

If they say you are too valuable in your current position then ask why you have not been promoted.

It they ask why tell them I don't seem to be able to get promoted in my current position so I want to expand my base of skills to hopefully get a promotion.